# How to use RegEx to match an integer before or after a specific character in Unix sed command?

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

How to use RegEx to match an integer before or after a specific character in Unix sed command?

Suppose we have a sed-numbers file:

```
cat sed-numbers 
(1, 2)
(4, 5)
(2, 3)
```

Now I can use sed to switch `(x, y)` to `(y, x)` but I don't know how to select the first integer without select character`(`, so, I have to add a `(` character in front of pattern `\2` to accomplish the task:

```
sed 's/^(\([0-9]*\), \([0-9]*\)/(\2, \1/' sed-numbers
(2, 1)
(5, 4)
(3, 2)
```

Is there any method I can do the switch without add `(` in my switch pattern? In other words, can I use RegEx to select the first integer only and it has to be right after `(` instead of select `(+integer`?

Additional question:
What if we only need to switch position if the first number is an integer and the data format is:

```
(11, 2) 
(0.2, 5) 
(2.1, 3) 
(4, 2.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input is in the exact format you mentioned in the question then you could use the below sed commnad,

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9]*\), \([0-9]*\)/\2, \1/' file
(2, 1)
(5, 4)
(3, 2)
```

You could do this simply through Perl using lookbehind and lookahead,

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<=\()(\d+), (\d+)(?=\))/\2, \1/g' file
(2, 1)
(5, 4)
(3, 2)
```

**Update**

This would work for your updated question.

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<=\()(\d+), (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=\))/\2, \1/g' file
(2, 11) 
(0.2, 5) 
(2.1, 3) 
(2.1, 4)
```

Comment: What if the data format is (11, 2)
(0.2, 5)
(2.1, 3)
(4, 2.1)? And we only switch position if the first number is an integer.

Comment: could you update your question according to the above comment? Did you wanna perl solution?

Comment: Thanks for your awesome solutions! Addition to perl, is possible to solve the additional problem only use sed? BTW I tried your perl solution on the additional problem. It doesn't work with (4, 2.1), 4 is an integer, but it didn't switch the position.